# Highlight words in sentence

Tags: regex, grep

I have few sections of a book which contains matter of following format:

> Meanings 1:- Appreciate : understand value of something, situation, to be grateful. Regard:to think of somebody, best wishes. Mitigate:painful, unpleasant, etc.

> Meanings 2:- Deed: action. Associate:to make connection, spend time with somebody. Rejuvenate: to look younger, Reluctant : not willing.

I am looking for a grep which will match words before a colon. **Appreciate, Regard, Mitigate, Deed, Rejuvenate, Reluctant** in my case.

Some of the words have a space before the colon and some words doesnt have the space. Some words are continuous like **Regard, Mitigate**. There is no space before of after the colon.

The code which I have written is not working.

`\w*(?= ?:)`

I not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: AFAIK, `grep` doesn't support lookahead. Have a try with: `grep -e '\w+(?= ?:)' file`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It did work, however, how will it work if the matter is like this--
**Appreciate it:  or Thanks and Regards:**
Here I need to select multiple words and include the colon as well.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` doesn't support lookahead, but it will work if you use `-e` option:

```sh
grep -e '\w+(?= ?:)' file
```

If you want to match multiple words space separated, use:

```
grep -e '\w+(?: \w+)*(?= ?:)' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w+        # 1 or more word character (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
(?: \w+)*  # non capture group, a space and 1 or more word character, may appear 0 or more times
(?= ?:)    # positive lookahead, an optional space followed by a colon
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, however, the search is excluding the colon. It should include the colon as well. Secondly, I am unable to undestand the use of non-capturing group.

Comment: @Shahid: if you want to include the colon, remove the lookahead: `\w+(?: \w+)* ?:`, the non capture group is similar to capture group but much more efficient as it doesn't capture anything.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: @Shahid: You're welcome, glad it helps.